# Unable to disable eslint React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am new to React.js a pulled a project from github. When I run the app with `yarn start` the project runs with eslint.
Now i want to disable the eslint, i don't see an `.eslintrc.json` in the folder but it eslint works when I run the project.

How do i disable the eslint in react project completely ?

this is what i tried to add in `package.json`

```
...
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off"
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: yes...but i want to disable for the whole project. the above works only for a file

Comment: ESLint doesn't do anything by itself. Is your *IDE* using it?

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis which code editor you are using

Comment: Does your project have a `.eslintrc` file that specifies rules?

Comment: if you are using VSCODE go to extensions tab which is located at the left side of the screen in a vertical bar and search for eslint. click on it. It will give you an option to either disable it or uninstall the extension.